# C++ for loop to find "sum of digits of a given number"

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm a very beginner. I'm trying to solve some problems and being stuck right at the first one. The while loop runs but then I try using for loop and it never runs

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n=910;
int digits_sum=0;
for(int i=n;i=0;i/=10)
digits_sum+=(i%10);
cout<<digits_sum;
return 0;}
```

I googled and found on `codescrackers:`

```
int num, rem, sum;

cout<<"Enter the Number: ";
cin>>num;
for(sum=0; num>0; num=num/10)
{
    rem = num%10;
    sum = sum+rem;
}
cout<<"\nSum of Digits = "<<sum;
```

The code runs and it gives me other questions:

1. why is the init value sum=0?
2. Why is condition num>0

It seems I still don't get the `for` loop statement fully so this is how it runs with my understanding:

init value i = n = 910

condition to be out of the loop: i = 0

decrement: i = 910/10 = 91

Could you please tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: _"condition to be out of loop: i=0"_ - no, that's an assignment, you mean `i == 0`. But you also need to think about the logic. `i == 0` means "keep repeating as long as `i` equals 0". Is this really what you want?

Comment: use `-Wall -Werror` the compiler can help you: https://godbolt.org/z/s9hPq9, clang is so nice to tell you all the details, what is wrong and how to fix it

Comment: This would be C, not C++ but I'd sprintf the number to a string and grab the chars one at a time until the asciiz, and add each char to an int initialized to zero.

Comment: @ArthurKalliokoski you can do the same in C++, you just wouldnt use sprintf for it

Comment: @churill for loop example: for(int i=0;i>10;++i), then i>10 is the condition to stop the loop right?

Comment: `i = 0` assigns `0` to `i`. `i == 0` compares `i` to `0`. You want the latter, because the first always evaluates to `false`

Comment: You don't actually want the latter either. You want `for (int i=n; i != 0; i/=10)` Think about it. And yes, you can shorten that to `for (int i=n; i; i/=10)`

Comment: @churill thank you very much, my bad, I will fix my code but could you please explain me why is the init value sum=0 from codescrackers, thank you very much

Comment: Thank you you guys, you save my day! Wish you all the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quoute from your question:

> condition to be out of loop: i=0

You have two misunderstandings here:

1. `i = 0` is an assignment, you want a comparison `i == 0`
2. It looks you interpreted this as "exit if this is condition is fullfilled", but in fact the opposite happens: The loop will continue as long as this condition is true.

So the only thing you have to do is to change

```
for(int i=n;i=0;i/=10)
```

to

```
for(int i = n; i != 0; i /= 10) // loop as long as i does not equal 0
```